# Parse a string containing percent sign into decimal

Tags: c#

I have a simple string containing VAT-percantage value that needs to be stored in a decimal. The string looks like this: "19.00%". When I use the decimal.Parse() methode I always get an FormatException.

Code looks like this

```
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo() 
                                              {
                                                  PercentDecimalSeparator = ".",
                                                  PercentSymbol = "%"
                                              };
    decimal.Parse("19.00%",NumberStyles.Any, nfi);
```

I know, that it would be possible (in the example above) to simply remove the %-char from the string and then parse. But isn't there a solution to use built in parsing, which can be used without testing the string for the type of number the user typed in.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171615/how-to-convert-percentage-string-to-double

Comment: Thanks! Did not find this when searching the site.
So I guess there isn't a way to get around changing the string.

Comment: @Robert Harvey why would you close something that's useful? What gives you the the right to decide it's "Too localized"? I was looking for an answer to this question and apparently your high mightiness thinks it doesn't need an answer.

Comment: @bleepzter: Are you aware that this question is seven years old, and that it sat unanswered for 3 years before I finally closed it?   Remove the percent sign and use `Decimal.Parse`, or see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2171615