# I want to turn a percentage value string to double?

Tags: c#, math, format, rounding

I have a percentage string in c# and want to return it into a double value.

for example . . .

```
string p = "6%";
```

Now I want to turn this string into

```
double value = 0.06;
```

How  can I so that? I tried to use Math.Round() and put -2 in the digits to be rounded but it only allows numbers 0-15.

I am glad for any help you could offer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert percentage string to double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171615/how-to-convert-percentage-string-to-double)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
double value = double.Parse(p.TrimEnd(new[] {'%'}))/100;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using split and cast it to double

```
double value = double.Parse(p.Split(new char[]{'%'})[0]) / 100;
```

Comment: You cannot _cast_ a string to a double.

Comment: But you apparently _can_ get upvotes by saying you can cast a string to a double.

Comment: double value = double.Parse( p.Split('%')[0] ) / 100;

Answer (score 1):

```
   double value = double.Parse(p.Trim().Split('%')[0]) / 100;
```

Comment: +1 Well, I would use Double.Parse(p.TrimRight(' ', '%')) to do _little bit_ more error checking (or "6%abc" may be considered valid) but it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
string p = "6%";
string p2 = p.Remove(p.Length - 1);
double value = Convert.ToDouble(p2) / 100;
```

Comment: Careful, this will result in integer division.

Comment: Almost. Your division will yield `0`. `6 / 100 == 0`, `6 / 100.0 == 0.06`

Comment: I think casting the p2 into a double will sort this?

Comment: Yes, but it was ToInt32 in the 1st revision.