# Percentage comparison operator on string

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PowerShell in school, I have a basic question regarding percentage calculations:

```
$foo = "10%"
$bar = "5%"
$foo -gt $bar
False
```

I tried converting to integer type:

```
[int]$foo -gt [int]$bar
Cannot convert value "10%" to type "System.Int32". 
Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Is there a percentage data type in PowerShell? Or a comparison operator for working with percentages?

Comment: No and no. PowerShell can *format* percentages by using the .NET formatting facilities (e.g. `(0.5).ToString("0%")`) but it cannot parse them (and neither can the .NET formatting facilities). There are (rather elaborate) [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2171615/4137916) on the .NET level, but for PowerShell it's perhaps simplest to just remove the percent and parse (i.e. `[double] ("10%" -replace "%", "")`, even though this may not be strictly correct for all cultures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, but you can trim them to quickly extract the integer part:

```
PS> [int]$foo.trim('%') -gt [int]$bar.trim('%')
True
```