# Read textbox in to a double without Percent

Tags: c#, double

my question is i write a textbox with a double in Percentage but after i read this textbox and i put this in other double but how ?

```
 Actuallyday24.Text = day25oee24d.ToString("P2");
 double Gridactually24    = double.Parse(Actuallyday24.Text);
```

what is my mistake ?

Comment: `Trim` the `%` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this .

also u can find this with easy research :

[How to convert percentage string to double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171615/how-to-convert-percentage-string-to-double)

```
 value = value.Replace(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol, "");
```

[image: Example]

```
textBox2.Text = "15%";

    var K = textBox2.Text;

    K = K.Replace(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol, "");

    double test = Convert.ToDouble(K);
```

Comment: okay but i will read the textbox  double test    = double.Parse(Textbox.Text);

Comment: and this dosent work...

Comment: its works check the answer .

Comment: okay i make a miss take thx you ! :)